# Java Graphics Multiple Classes

Tags: java, swing, graphics

i have a slight problem. I am trying to write a program that draws a box of crayons. I want to have a method i can call from a main applet that draws a crayon. Currently, my main program looks like this:

```
package Crayons;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CrayonBox extends JApplet 
{
 public void paint (Graphics page)
 {
  final int CENTER = 250;
  final int SQUARE_SIZE = 31;

  Crayon.drawCrayon(CENTER-5*SQUARE_SIZE, CENTER+5*SQUARE_SIZE, 9*SQUARE_SIZE,Color.red);
  page.set
 }
    }
```

and my supporting program that has methods to draw the crayon looks like this:

```
package Crayons;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Crayon extends CrayonBox
{


public static void drawCrayon (int x, int y, int height, Color color)
 {
  Polygon crayonTip = new Polygon();
  crayonTip.addPoint(x+15, y);
  crayonTip.addPoint(x+46, y);
  crayonTip.addPoint(x+62, y-62);
  crayonTip.addPoint(x+62, y);
  page.setColor(color);
 }
    }
```

i now need the second program to draw the poylgon i created using

```
page.drawPolygon(crayonTip);
```

and change the color using

```
page.setColor(color);
```

but it says that page cannot be resolved. so it cannot control the page command. Which is very annoying. Is ther a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `paint` method is passed a `Graphics` object to handle drawing.  You can pass this object to any helper methods by passing the `page` object to those methods.  Your `drawCrayon` method then becomes:

```
public static void drawCrayon (int x, int y, int height, Color color, Graphics page)
 {
  ...
  page.setColor(color);
 }
```